# Dynamic schema generation from array of columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I had a list of columns, By using these columns prepared a schema

code :

```
import  org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val fields = Array("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6")
val dynSchema = StructType( fields.map( field =>
       new StructField(field, StringType, true, null) ) )
```

then schema prepared as

```
StructType(StructField(col1,StringType,true), StructField(col2,StringType,true), 
           StructField(col3,StringType,true), StructField(col4,StringType,true),
           StructField(col5,StringType,true), StructField(col6,StringType,true))
```

But I am getting `NullPointerException` when I  try to read the data from a json file using above schema.

```
// reading the data
spark.read.schema(dynSchema).json("./file/path/*.json")
```

But it is working if I add array to StructType. 
Please help me to generate dynamic schema.

Edit : If i create schema with above fields, I can able to read the data from json.

```
 StructType(Array(
 StructField("col1",StringType,true), StructField("col2",StringType,true), 
 StructField("col3",StringType,true), StructField("col4",StringType,true), 
 StructField("col5",StringType,true), StructField("col6",StringType,true)))
```

Comment: What does your json look like?

Comment: It throws error because your JSON is not matching with your `dynSchema `.

Comment: @Rex , I updated the question, with the same columns I can able to read the data.

Comment: @C.S.ReddyGadipally, JSON file might be have those columns. But we are reading with `schema` then  all schema columns should return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the null argument from the creation of the `StructField` as follows:

```
val dynSchema = StructType( fields.map( field =>
     new StructField(field, StringType, true)))
```

The last argument is used to define metadata about the column. Its default value is not `null` but `Metadata.empty`. See [the source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructField.scala) for more detail. In the source code, they assume that it cannot be null and call methods on it without any checks. This is why you get a `NullPointerException`.